# NodeJs request data stream vs expressJs bodyParser

Tags: node.js, http, express, post, body-parser

I am working on a legacy project of NodeJS using a very old **node version of 0.12.2**

Though it is using an **expressJS framework version 4.12.4** with **body-parser version 1.8.1**

Some of the old controllers utilize the native nodeJS method of reading the data stream from the request object to access the body part of the request:

```
req.on("data", function (data) {
    body += data;
});
req.on("end", function () { 
    console.log(body)
    // do something here with body
}
```

The newer controllers use the `bodyParser` to access the data using the following method:

```
req.body('something')
```

The body parser is instantiated as:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

This is a very large project (1300+ Api's) running as a production level software.

My question is, is the above a safe practice? 
Would using bodyParser affect the native request object?

The trouble I am facing is sometimes the legacy controllers time out without returning any response, there are no logs generated, hence unable to debug.